# Cordova , jquerymobile

Tags: cordova

I am trying to create Cordova application with jquerymobile.

Jquerymobile 1.3.0
Cordova 5+

My application has 3 pages . Index login and menu page

I am loading all script 's. In index.html (including Cordova.js)

When I comment Cordova js application is working fine.(from index-login-menu)

But when I uncommented Cordova.js in index.html. App not running stays in index HTML.

How to resolve this..

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an error happening somewhere whenever cordova.js is available.

Do your code uses the "deviceready" cordova event? i.e: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`

If yes, check the code there, it might have some issues. Additionally, helpful idea can be to debug you application with Chrome or something similar to see if there are any errors in the console.

If you post some code It can be helpful.

Hope this helps.